# What is the cause for an HTTP 405 Error in GAE application?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

I'm using eclipse to develop a Google App Engine application.  I am on a login page, but I click login, then it shows "Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL"?

Here is my servlet code:

**my LgServlet.java:**

```
package com.lan;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class LgServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
                check(req,resp);
            }
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
                check(req,resp);
                }

    public void check(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        if(req.getAttribute("userID").equals("admin")&&req.getAttribute("userPassword").equals("123456")){
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Hello Admin");
        }
}

}
```

**my web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>lg</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.lan.LgServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>lg</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/lg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**part of index.jsp:**

```
<form action="lg" method="post">
```

I hope someone can help explain to me why I'm getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<form action="lg" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="/lg" method="post">
```

Nothing else looks out of place. I got this error recently, but it was because i was calling super.doPost() in my doPost call.

HTH

Comment: Old thread/ answer, but having `super.doPost()`, where 'super' is  `HttpServlet` will cause 405.